# How do I find the short circuit current in a CMOS inverter? I also want to extend this idea into other complex circuits with CMOS inverters

Tags: inverter, cmos

I wanted to find the short circuit current in a CMOS inverter. I read "chapter 5 ,Digital IC (Rabaey.)" When I tried to make a CMOS inverter, I am very confused about what the 'short circuit current' is. The current through the drain of the  PMOS is not equal to the current through the source, same is true with NMOS. Which current is the short circuit current? In the text, the shape was approximated as a triangle.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's called shoot-through current not short-circuit current.

Comment: @Andyaka Actually the heading was direct path current , but in between the paragraph it was used short circuit current. Are direct current and shoot through current same ? or short circuit current and direct path current same ?

Comment: @Andyaka  When I googled shoot-through current , it said thats when Vdd tries to pull and GND tries to push at the same time. So effectively some current is used to charge the Cload(and parasitic capacitances ) while some will flow to GND ? Is this what happens in the circuit?

Comment: Shoot-through is when both MOSFETs are partially on at the same time.

Comment: What about short circuit /direct path current ? I thought these meant there is a path between Vdd and GND which appears to be same as your explanation for shoot current. Does 'partially' make the diffence between the two?  @Andyaka

Comment: I have no idea what text you get your definitions from AND does it really matter? If the text you are working to has not got a great definition of these currents then, in effect you are asking someone to guess on your behalf and that means an "opinion". I can tell you what I think it means (shoot-through current) but, there's no point taking it further if the text is unclear.

Comment: Can you suggest a text. I wanted to find the short circuit current(Thats what I though it was called) in this circuit. Text I am following is Digital integrated circuit: design perspective by Rabaey. My aim was to find the dynamic power dissipation in this circuit and I wanted to understand the short circuit loss. @Andyaka

Comment: No, sorry I can't.

Comment: Like you cant suggest a text or you cant clear the question? its fine if you cant suggest a text , is the question too vague or am I missing something ? @Andyaka

Comment: No, sorry I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [all the figures have errors illustration by my simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCBMCmC0YTAZgHQAYCcB2ALGArEpGGgBxikBsEOGI%209a9cCAUAGZRaTg44hIklXv0QoGadJA5cekHE0HD5TJmHEhJaaQHcBQ8JUUGwGHmlZ6l4M-uXzNl2SOenzTyNxtyvKxwCU7cEhSINJVTRAFekjVcVYAcyDIfGFrENDVDy83KDJvRwBjPNDcyHyU4TV0NFq6%20vqwFhoUDDb29txPWy00MESSqFTBjNjWACdB3LA%20ArVa1mKhUttloarwFFIWONrBLFJ8UlIsGdI%20LG0qmv6rShWea1yLO9DK5OGLBSQo2oEefAhEAYDaQAD6lBwYLQYIU2DB%20GhKHBMPB4KQrG%20vyYngBQOsighUJhcKwCKRKLB6LBGMCM1EtgQPGeUHADT%20kA0nIkmniWIUalsgLen2CROhYLAKRwiN6fSRCCwGBwl0olBBpAw2hlEvBUppYIAwgBBAAKmLQPwF4Cl9CBYCwG31kIleDQlHJkkpeupJvNAA8hsYsFEwGloqJ%20ABVADO0AAOjGAC4ACwArgBbABGOhT0GgABtE0mAPaJwopgCGADsEgmY4bWEA) in the location of \$I_{SC}\$ and arrow.
[image]
For a rising input, the supply current comes from the Nch low side driver and not the high side as shown.  However, initially from t=0 the high side would be the only active drive as a "big" load cap charges up.

This shoot-thru is maximum when Vin near Vdd/2  at the input threshold casing a low  RdsOn for each FET to be ON at the same time between both FETs.

***A large external capacitance diverts the shoot-thru current to the outside cap and increases the duration of the current pulse.***
Internal Miller Capacitance is the cause of latency and simultaneous shoot thru. **Beyond this time with a large load C, only one (1) driver is active, so it is not shoot-thru for that period.**
Increasing the load capacitance simply increases the current pulse width.

**Ron for each family of logic controls current limit**

CD4xxx family @ 12V RdsOn = 300 Ohm @ , @ 3V > 1kOhm
74HCxx family @ 5V RdsOn = 50  Ohms +/-25%
74ALCxx family at 3.3V = 25 ohms +/- 25%

**This is why it is important to add decoupling cap. for each CMOS IC.**

[image]

### Dynamic Power consumption

In computing the power dissipation for shootthru power dissipation or "dynamic" power as it is normally called, you could compute the change in energy of the Miller Capacitance and divide by the time interval between transitions or compute V*I=P for each transition.
[image]

updated plot to show Pavg

Comment: I think I understood what you explained. But the current I am looking for is the current from Vdd to GND. Any current flowing through Vdd has to either go to GND or charge any capacitor right? So I wanted to know how much current will flow directly from Vdd-M1-M2-GNd. And then calculate the power dissipated due to this . @Tony

Comment: Dear Hari, Since Vt & RdsOn has a wide tolerance (25%)  you can estimate with assumptions using RdsOn and time duration.  But my 2nd plot computes the product of VI max For average power, you should use the PW50% pulse width. or % duty cycle @ 10MHz in this example.

Comment: It’s not what you requested but I showed the power from supply and power dissipated in each device. does it add up?

Comment: To be honest I am still confused but I appreciate you effort.  I am still reading the answer you wrote @Tony

Comment: When load C exceeds Miller C on driver, the external current begins to draw more current than the shootthru current. Ic=CdV/dt depending on ESR and Ron. The cap is ideal as shown and thus lossless (on average) but **causes losses on alternate switch transitions.**

Comment: Okay I think I understood the answer. But then my aim was to quantify the shoot thru current (I thought this was called short circuit/direct path current) , I understood the advantage of the external capacitance but that slows the circuit. So I wanted to quantify this shoot thru  current for different values of external capacitance.  I am unable to find the shoot thru current.  @Tony

Comment: Dear HK, drag the load cap off on my simulation then you will see it. Or use mouse wheel to reduce C.  There is no advantage to adding load caps.  In similar discrete power half bridges, deadtime must be carefully designed.

Comment: I have specified the source and drain area (I can control the intrinsic capacitance).The circuit you shared is somewhat same circuit I made in LTSPICE. is the current flowing through NMOS the shoot thru current?  @Tony

Comment: Is it possible to find the actual current  used to charge the intrinsic capacitances and current that directly flow to GND ? @Tony

Comment: Sure by testing or simulation. It’s pretty dynamic and variable for a detailed model. Q is nonlinear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127201/discussion-between-hari-krishna-and-tony-stewart-ee75).